# Is it possible to read substring from char to char

Tags: javascript

I mean I want to read a substring inside #:example_text

For example, if a have "Good Morning #:Lucy:# and #:karl:#" it will return Lucy and Karl

I want to make a text replacer which will iterate over string and when he will get #:test#: he will replace that for the value of a key #:test#

For now, I don't have any idea how can I do this.

Comment: a regex can be your friend.

Comment: What is the `#:` means? some flag to know that it is a replacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) with JavaScript's `string.replace(regex, callback)`:

```
var str = "Good Morning #:name:# and #:friend:#";
var replacements = {
    name: "Jake",
    friend: "Finn"
}

str = str.replace(/#:(.+?):#/g, function(match, id) {
    return replacements[id];
});
```

`str.replace(regex, callback)` will look for parts of the string `str` that match the pattern `regex`, and will replace it by what `callback` returns for each instance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel, just use regex for that. But to answer your question, you can access each char of a string using its index like an array. Example:

```
var msg = "Good Morning #:Lucy:# and #:karl:#" 
var first_char = msg[0]; //will return G.
```